# How would I go about solving this 3 Chests problem?

Tags: logic

How would I go about solving this 3 Chests problem?

I need to either solve or prove that the following riddle is unsolvable.

1. Chest A contains gold if Chest B contains gold or if Chest C contains gold.
2. Chest B contains gold if Chest C contains gold and Chest A contains silver.
3. Chest C contains gold if Chest A contains silver.

I've created truth tables based on the 3 statements.
How do I go about either solving it or proving that it can't be solved?

Comment: Too  many "if"s in $1$. Can a chest have silver AND gold? And what is "chest" anyway?

Comment: Treat it like a system of equations: 3 variables and 3 equations.  You can immediately reduce this to two variables and 2 equations by substitution.  What you then have should simplify and the answer should be clear.  I am assuming from your tables that each chest must contain silver or gold, but not both.

Comment: Assume $A$, then by 3. $!C$ and by 1. $B\ ||\ C$. But since $!C$ already $B\ ||\ C$ yields just $B$. But then by 2. $C\ \&\&\ !A$ ... contradiction.

Now assume $!A$, and continue the argument ...

Comment: question should specify that each chest must contain either silver or gold. otherwise $A$ can have anything other than silver or gold and $B$ and $C$ anything other than gold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your translation is correct, and you can just build a truth table of the conjunction of all your above 3 clauses to see if it's satisfiable or not.

$$A~~|B~~|C~~|~~(A↔(B∨C))∧(B↔(C∧(¬A)))∧(C↔(¬A))$$

And use some online tool like [this](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%7E3((A%7E4(B%7E2C))%7E1(B%7E4(C%7E1(%7E3A)))%7E1(C%7E4(%7E3A)))) you can quickly see its negation is a tautology, thus this puzzle as interpreted by your above logic translation is unsolvable since it's a negation of a tautology (aka a contradiction)...

Comment: Thanks! How do we know to translate "p if q" into $p \leftrightarrow q$ instead of, for example, $p \leftarrow q$?

Comment: @joseville Thanks for your further checking! This was from a while ago and I remember I interpreted "p if q" here as a definitional logical equivalence of "p", and no one pointed out to me so far... Yes you have a point here and luckily I just checked same after changing ↔ to ←, and same conclusion still holds. And the gist of my answer here is the object language formation from meta.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution to this problem.

If $A$ contains gold then either chest $B$ or $C$ contain gold. $C$ contains gold if and only if $A$ contains silver. Therefore $C$ does not contain gold and so, $B$ must contain gold which means $C$ contains gold which is a contradiction.

If $A$ contains silver then $C$ contains gold which means $A$ contains gold. This is also a contradiction.

Therefore, there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming each chest contains either silver or gold.

If C contains gold, then A contains silver (Statement $3$), so B contains gold (Statement $2$).  This contradicts Statement $1$.

If C does not contain gold, then A does not contain silver (Statement $3$), so B does not contain gold (Statement $2$).  Again, (if A contains either silver or gold, this forces A to contain gold), this contradicts Statement $1$.

The combination therefore has no solution.